# Number of non-adjacent sets of a given size

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

If you are given the set `L={1,2,3,...,N}` and an integer `k`, is it possible to efficiently calculate the number of "non-adjacent" subsets of size `k`? A subset `S` is non-adjacent if for each `x` in `S`, neither `x-1` nor `x+1` are in `S`.

As an example, for `L={1,2,3,4}` and `k=2` the answer is 3, because we have 
`{1,3},{1,4},{2,4}`. For `k=3` the answer is zero.

One way to go would be to generate all size 2 non-adjacent subsets, then trying all possible unions (since a non-adjacent set has the property that all its subsets are non-adjacent), but that strikes me as very wasteful, and probably there is a sweet elegant efficient solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by `S(m,n)` the number of non-adjacent subsets of size `m` in `{1,...,n}`. Then the following holds:

```
S(m,n) = S(m,n-1) + S(m-1,n-2)
```

So one can solve it by DP in `O(Nk)`, by adding the boundary conditions

```
S(1,n) = n
S(m,1) = I(m==1)
S(m,2) = 2*I(m==1)
```

where `I()` is the indicator function.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it in this way: if you knew what the answer is for the set `L'={1, 2, 3, ..., N - 1}`, could you use that information to build the answer for the set `L`?
The idea is that when you add `N` to `L'`, the new solution is made of all the subsets available for `L'` plus 1 new subset for each of the elements of `L'` that are less or equal than `N - 2*(k - 1)`, so if solution for `L'` had a size of `V'`, then `V` the solution for `L` will be `V = V' + (N - 2*(k - 1))`
If you work it out a bit more, you'll find that the solution can be expressed as the sum of the first `N - 2k + 2` natural integers.

About the less or equal than `N - 2*(k - 1)` part, the new number `N` being added will only add to subsets whose final number is less or equal than the result of that expression, because there must be `k` elements in the new subset being built (including the number `N` itself, so there are `k - 1` more needed) separated each other by a minimum of 2 numbers each, which makes a distance of `2*(k - 1)` from the number `N`, and so the expression.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't follow the part about "less or equal than N - 2*(k - 1)". But your final formula seems wrong: N-k-1 for N=4 and k=2 equals 4-2-1=1, so you would return 1 rather than 3.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when calculating the formula. It should be right now

Comment: I've also added an explanation of what you didn't understand. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the added info! It still seems incorrect to me though. Take N=6 and k=3. Then we should have sets 135, 136, 146 and 246, i.e. answer 4. However the formula N-2k+2=2 yields 1+2=3.

Comment: Your answer inspired me to see a solution which seems correct and reasonably efficient. Denote by #(m,n) the number of non-adjacent subsets of size m in {1,...,n}. Then the following holds: #(m,n)=#(m,n-1)+#(m-1,n-1). Of course a solution like your would be much nicer because easier to compute.

Comment: Actually, that should be #(m,n)=#(m,n-1)+#(m-1,n-2).

Answer (score 1):

This may be along the same lines as Win32's solution, but I wasn't sure.  So I am posting it separately.

Take S(n) to be the number of non-adjacent subsets of your consecutive sequence of size n (i.e., S(n) is the solution you are looking for).

Let us calculate S(n+1), the value when we add an element to the sequence.  When we add an element k, we increase the number of non-adjacent subsets of that sequence.  We can break down these *new* subsets into the following categories.

- The subsets containing solely the new element we added.  There is just one of these ({k}).
- The subsets to which we can add k and still retain our non-adjacent criteria (plus k).  We can add k to any subset that doesn't contain k-1 while maintaining non-adjacency.  Another way of saying this is that we can add k to subsets that contain at most k-2.  And the number of subsets that contain at most k-2 is equal to S(n-1).

So the number of new non-adjacent subsets when we add k to our sequence is 1 + S(n-1).  In other words, 1 + S(n-1) = S(n+1) - S(n).  We can rearrange this formula to get S(n+1) = 1 + S(n-1) + S(n).

Recursive solutions are not very helpful, so we can attempt to generalize it.  I am not good at this step, but [Wolfram|Alpha is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=S%28n%2b1%29%20=%201%20%2b%20S%28n-1%29%20%2b%20S%28n%29;%20S%281%29%20=%201;%20S%280%29%20=%200,%20S%282%29%20=%202), and we find the general formula is equal to the following.

- S(n) = 1/2 * (3 * [Fib](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fibonacci.html)(n) + [Lucas](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LucasL.html)(n) - 2)

Here are some sample data points.

```
n | S(n)
0 | 0
1 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 4
4 | 7
5 | 12
6 | 20
7 | 33
8 | 54
9 | 88
```

Comment: And I now realize I completely forgot about the problem of solving for a set of a particular cardinailty.  Perhaps it's still of use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and for the additional info -- I was struggling to understand why you were using k in that way :) I agree with your reasoning and think it is correct for the sum over all cardinalities. I had no idea WolframAlpha solved such systems.

Comment: Hi @cheeken, since I think the answer is related with my question, do you mind taking a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75733723/17901455 , please?

Answer (score 0):

Let:

> `S(n,k)` be the set of non-adjacent subsets of `{1,...n}` of size `k`

Clearly, `S(n-1,k)` is a set of non-adjacent subsets of size `k` and it is a subset of `S(n,k)`.

Also, `S(n-2,k-1)` is a set of non-adjacent subsets of size `k-1`, and none of these subsets include `n-1`.  Thus, we can safely add `{n}` to each of these subsets to get subsets of size `k`.  And since they do not include `n-1` (the only adjacent element to `n`), they are also non-adjacent.

Thus:

> `S(n,k) = S(n-1,k) U ({n} X S(n-2,k-1))`

Using some real numbers, lets try to solve for `S(6,3)`.

```
S(6,3) = S(5,3) U ({6} X S(4,2))
 S(5,3) = {1,3,5}                   # Only one solution
  S(4,2) = S(3,2) U ({4} X S(2,1))
   S(3,2) = {1,3}                   # Only one solution
    S(2,1) = {1} {2}                # All sets of 1 element are non-adjacent
   {4} X S(2,1) = {1,4} {2,4}       # Add {4} to each
  S(4,2) = {1,3} {1,4} {2,4}
 {6} X S(4,2) = {1,3,6} {1,4,6} {2,4,6}
S(6,3) = {1,3,5} {1,3,6} {1,4,6} {2,4,6}
```

Which matches your answer.

Now, to compute the number:

> Let `N(n,k)` be the number of elements in `S(n,k)`

Then:

> `N(n,k) = N(n-1,k) + N(n-2,k-1)`

I haven't yet determined the closed form, but here are some computed values:

```
 n    k=1   k=2   k=3   k=4   k=5   k=6   k=7   k=8   k=9  k=10  k=11  k=12  k=13
 1     1                                                                        
 2     2                                                                        
 3     3     1                                                                  
 4     4     3                                                                  
 5     5     6     1                                                            
 6     6    10     4                                                            
 7     7    15    10     1                                                      
 8     8    21    20     5                                                      
 9     9    28    35    15     1                                                
10    10    36    56    35     6                                                
11    11    45    84    70    21     1                                          
12    12    55   120   126    56     7                                          
13    13    66   165   210   126    28     1                                    
14    14    78   220   330   252    84     8                                    
15    15    91   286   495   462   210    36     1                              
16    16   105   364   715   792   462   120     9                              
17    17   120   455  1001  1287   924   330    45     1                        
18    18   136   560  1365  2002  1716   792   165    10                        
19    19   153   680  1820  3003  3003  1716   495    55     1                  
20    20   171   816  2380  4368  5005  3432  1287   220    11                  
21    21   190   969  3060  6188  8008  6435  3003   715    66     1            
22    22   210  1140  3876  8568 12376 11440  6435  2002   286    12            
23    23   231  1330  4845 11628 18564 19448 12870  5005  1001    78     1      
24    24   253  1540  5985 15504 27132 31824 24310 11440  3003   364    13      
25    25   276  1771  7315 20349 38760 50388 43758 24310  8008  1365    91     1
26    26   300  2024  8855 26334 54264 77520 75582 48620 19448  4368   455    14
```

Comment: Hi @Trenin, since I think your last answer here is related with my question, do you mind to look at this question, please?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/75733723/17901455